# Background task polling external resource at certain intervals

Tags: asp.net, .net, architecture

Requirement: I need to create a background worker/task that will get data from an external source ( message queue) at certain intervals ( i.e. 10s) and update a database. Need to run non stop 24hrs. An ASP.NET application is placing the data to the message queue.

Possible solutions:

1. Windows service with timer

   - Pros: Takes load away from web server
   - Cons: Separate deployment overhead, Not load balanced
2. Use one of the methods described here : [background task](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

   - Pros: No separation deployment required, Can be load balanced - if one    server goes down another can pick it up
   - Cons: Overhead on web server (however, in my case with max 100 concurrent users and seeing the web server resources are under-utilized, I do not think it will be an issue)

Question: What would be a recommended solution and why?
I am looking for a .net based solution.

Comment: I would go with option 1. Why?  There would be a lot of factors you would consider when making a choice.  Perhaps its not important but more load u can push off a web server into other components, the faster your web server will respond to requests.

Comment: @Mick Thanks. I elaborated my question following your reply. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't go with the second option unless there's a really good reason for it. Decoupling your background jobs from your web application brings a number of advantages:

1. Scalability - It's up to you where to deploy the service. It can share the same server with the web application or you can easily move it to a different server if you see the load going up.
2. Robustness - If there's a critical bug in either the web application or the service this won't bring the other component down.
3. Maintanance - Yes, there's a slight overhead as you will have to adjust your deployment process but it's as simple as copying all binaries from the output folder and you will have to do it once only. On the other hand, you won't have to redeploy the application thus brining it down for some time if you just need to fix a small bug in the service.
4. etc.

Though I recommend you to go with the first option I don't like the idea with timer. There's a much simpler and robust solution. I would implement a WCF service with MSMQ binding as it provides you with a lot of nice features out of the box:

1. You won't have to implement polling logic. On start up the service will connect to the queue and will sit waiting for new messages.
2. You can easily use transaction to process queue messages. For example, if there's something wrong with the database and you can't write to it the message which is being processed at the moment won't get lost. This will get back to the queue to be processed later.
3. You can deploy as many services listening to the same queue as you wish to ensure scalability and availability. WCF will make sure that the same queue message is not processed by more than one service that is if a message is being processed by service A, service B will skip it and get the next available message.
4. Many other features you can learn about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048(v=vs.110).aspx).

I suggest reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008(v=vs.110).aspx) article for a WCF + MSMQ service sample and see how simple it is to implement one and use the features I mentioned above. As soon as you are done with the WCF service you can [easily host it in a windows service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Apologies for the late comment. Thank you Maksym for the excellent reply. Regarding reference to MSMQ you made, I must read messages from IBM Websphere MQ instead.

Comment: No problem. The suggested solution was just a side note and it's up to you how to implement it but when it comes to choosing between windows service and web application background tasks I'm pretty sure you should go with windows service unless there's something important you didn't mention in the question